# Use Metal Performance Shaders to compute SVD

Tags: metal, metal-performance-shaders

Can I use (a combination of) the existing Metal Performance Shaders to compute an SVD decomposition of a rectangular matrix? I see they only have QR and LU decompositions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVD speed in CPU and GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797226/svd-speed-in-cpu-and-gpu)

Comment: @codetiger so you’re suggesting it’s not implemented in Metal Performance Shaders because there would be no computational benefits of doing it on GPU, so I should just do it on CPU?

Comment: Am saying there is no default SVD implemented in Metal performance shaders. However, you can implement it using custom performance shader. Based on other implementations (Based on a quick search) it shows that we are not getting much benefit in implementing SVD on GPU

Comment: matrix factorizations aren't easily parallelizable on the gpu. there are papers out there to implement parallel QR or SVD decomposition, however you won't see much benefit unless, if they're batched.

where do you see QR decomposition in MPS btw?