# Undefined reference to `cusolverDn` functions

Tags: cuda, eigenvalue, eigenvector, cusolver

I need to calculate eigenvalue of a big matrix in parallel. For that purpose I use cuSolver. To test, how it works, I took code from documentation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>


void printMatrix(int m, int n, const double*A, int lda, const char* name)
{
    for(int row = 0 ; row < m ; row++){
        for(int col = 0 ; col < n ; col++){
            double Areg = A[row + col*lda];
            printf("%s(%d,%d) = %f\n", name, row+1, col+1, Areg);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    cusolverDnHandle_t cusolverH = NULL;
    cusolverStatus_t cusolver_status = CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    cudaError_t cudaStat1 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat2 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat3 = cudaSuccess;
    const int m = 3;
    const int lda = m;
/*       | 3.5 0.5 0 |
 *   A = | 0.5 3.5 0 |
 *       | 0   0   2 |
 *
 */
    double A[lda*m] = { 3.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 2.0};
    double lambda[m] = { 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

    double V[lda*m]; // eigenvectors
    double W[m]; // eigenvalues

    double *d_A = NULL;
    double *d_W = NULL;
    int *devInfo = NULL;
    double *d_work = NULL;
    int  lwork = 0;

    int info_gpu = 0;

    printf("A = (matlab base-1)\n");
    printMatrix(m, m, A, lda, "A");
    printf("=====\n");

    // step 1: create cusolver/cublas handle
        cusolver_status = cusolverDnCreate(&cusolverH);
        assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusolver_status);

    // step 2: copy A and B to device
        cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_A, sizeof(double) * lda * m);
        cudaStat2 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_W, sizeof(double) * m);
        cudaStat3 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&devInfo, sizeof(int));
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);

        cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, sizeof(double) * lda * m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    // step 3: query working space of syevd
        cusolverEigMode_t jobz = CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR; // compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
        cublasFillMode_t uplo = CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER;
        cusolver_status = cusolverDnDsyevd_bufferSize(
            cusolverH,
            jobz,
            uplo,
            m,
            d_A,
            lda,
            d_W,
            &lwork);
        assert (cusolver_status == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS);

        cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_work, sizeof(double)*lwork);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    // step 4: compute spectrum
        cusolver_status = cusolverDnDsyevd(
            cusolverH,
            jobz,
            uplo,
            m,
            d_A,
            lda,
            d_W,
            d_work,
            lwork,
            devInfo);
        cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == cusolver_status);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

        cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(W, d_W, sizeof(double)*m, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaStat2 = cudaMemcpy(V, d_A, sizeof(double)*lda*m, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaStat3 = cudaMemcpy(&info_gpu, devInfo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
        assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);
        printf("after syevd: info_gpu = %d\n", info_gpu);
        assert(0 == info_gpu);

        printf("eigenvalue = (matlab base-1), ascending order\n");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
            printf("W[%d] = %E\n", i+1, W[i]);
        }

        printf("V = (matlab base-1)\n");
        printMatrix(m, m, V, lda, "V");
        printf("=====\n");

    // step 4: check eigenvalues
        double lambda_sup = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
            double error = fabs( lambda[i] - W[i]);
            lambda_sup = (lambda_sup > error)? lambda_sup : error;
        }
        printf("|lambda - W| = %E\n", lambda_sup);

    // free resources
        if (d_A    ) cudaFree(d_A);
        if (d_W    ) cudaFree(d_W);
        if (devInfo) cudaFree(devInfo);
        if (d_work ) cudaFree(d_work);

        if (cusolverH) cusolverDnDestroy(cusolverH);

        cudaDeviceReset();

        return 0;
    }
```

But after compiling it I got the next errors `` undefined reference to `cusolverDnCreate' ``, `undefined reference to cusolverDnDsyevd_bufferSize`,  `undefined reference to cusolverDnDsyevd` and `` undefined reference to `cusolverDnDestroy ``, but all that functions exist in <cusolverDn.h>.

The most strange thing, that when I try to compile this file as said there: [undefined reference to cusolverDn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284631/undefined-reference-to-cusolverdn) .
instead two first errors, which I listed above(others are the same) I got new errors: `identifier "cusolverEigMode_t" is undefined` and `identifier "CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR" is undefined`.

I try to solve it for couple of days, and will be really gratefull  if you help me!

Comment: You probably forgot to add compiler/linker options to link to a library that defines those identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link -lcusolver in your Makefile

Comment: I probably have never used makefiles, I am trying to do that, but aren't there any variants, how ti fix it inside IDE?

Comment: You can use add library in your IDE and add the cusolver to your project.