# Call multiple CUDA SVD (in cuSolver)

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, svd, cusolver

I would use the SVD routine of CUDA 7.0 (cuSolver), i need to perform the SVD on all parts where i split the matrix (for example, dividing the matrix into 2x2 blocks, I want to perform four times the SVD in parallel) . The idea would be to invoke several times the kernel in relation to the matrix subdivision. so:

```
for loop(istart){
   for loop(jstart){
       "invoke kernel"
   }
}
```

But in this way the call to the kernel is serial, not parallel. Since there isn't the possibility to invoke these functions from the kernel, how can I parallelise these calls?

Comment: Are you talking about cuSOLVER? How does your matrix structure look, for which parts do you need to perform SVD etc.? Be more specific.

Comment: Yes m.s. sorry, i edit!

Comment: Does this cover your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28380040/678093

Comment: Unfortunately not. This example run on the whole matrix. I need to invoke this routine on all parts of the matrix.

Comment: The answer mentions the creation of streams for this exact problem, did you try this?